# replace with regexp return undefined

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not so bad in regular expression but there I have a tiny problem, maybe one of you can answer this simple question.

I do this:

```
var myString = "10px";
var myRegexp = new RegExp("(\\d*\\.?\\d*){1}(em|ex|grad|ch|deg|ms|rad|rem|s|turn|vh|vw|vmin|vmax|px|cm|in|pt|pc|%)?", "gi");

myString.replace(myRegexp, function( match, number, type ){
    console.log(match, number, type);
});
```

The replace console log two time, the first is : `"10px", "10", "px"` and I don't know why there is a second time, it return me that: `,,undefined` (the two first value are not null or empty string, they return just nothing, absolutely empty).

My question, why the replace try a seconde replacing on nothing ? And how avoid it ?

Comment: Minor thing: `{1}` is completely pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your expression has everything optional, so you are also matching a zero-length string (an issue with javascript).  If I understand what you want to do, I don't think the number has to be optional, so you could try:

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(em|ex|grad|ch|deg|ms|rad|rem|s|turn|vh|vw|vmin|vmax|px|cm|in|pt|pc|%)?
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
 (\\d*\\.?\\d*){1}
```

Use start anchor:

```
^(\\d*\\.?\\d*)
```

As your regex has everything optional and matches empty string also.

Comment: Yes this solve the problem but if value is .5, the regexp dont match.

Comment: I find another solution, but the start anchor look better, it is (\\d*\\.\\d*|\\.)...

Comment: @anubhava I believe the OP wants to always match a number.  Your proposal will match an empty line

Comment: Nothing ! Your answer is good, the problem is my example, I said "10px".
It is only cause of the start anchor cant find 10px in "translateX(10px)", I did not think well before asking the question, I can't replace nothing by something, so the answer of Ron is better for avoiding any other problem. The solution is to do not search nothing. :)